# How do you convert [Dictionary<String, Any>] to [String: Any]?

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

I am sorting the array of dictionary able to do it below is the code but the out form is in

> [Dictionary<String, Any>.Element]
>
> I want in  [String: Any] how to do it

```swift
func sortWithTableColumn(datavalue:[[String : Any]]) -> [[String : Any]]{
    var allresult2 = [[Dictionary<String, Any>.Element]]()
    for dict in datavalue{
        let sortedrow = dict.sorted(by: { $0.key < $1.key })
        allresult2.append(sortedrow)
        
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want [String : Any] then why have you declared the return type as [[String : Any]]? And how do want to merge your dictionaries you receive? Please explain the logic for this and/or add an example with the expected result

Comment: @JoakimDanielson i want result in array of dict

Comment: That is not what your question is saying. Again, clarify your question and add an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is:

> Swift’s Dictionary type is an unordered collection. The order in which keys, values, and key-value pairs are retrieved when iterating over a dictionary is not specified.

So if you try convert Array of Tuples into Dictionary after sorting:

```
var newDict = [String : Any]
for (key, value) in sortedrow {
   newDict[key] = value
}
```

You get no-sorted dictionary. Again.
Instead of this you can try use Class or Struct:

```
struct SomeStruct {
    var key: String
    var someType: Any
}
```

Then convert your [Dictionary<String, Any>] to [[SomeStruct]]:

```
func sortWithTableColumn(datavalue:[[String : Any]]) -> [[SomeStruct]] {
    var allresult2 = [[SomeStruct]]()
        for dict in datavalue {
            let sortedrow = dict.sorted(by: { $0.key < $1.key })
            
            var newArray = [SomeStruct]()
            for (key, value) in sortedrow {
                newArray.append(SomeStruct(key: key, someType: value))
            }

            allresult2.append(newArray)
        }
    return allresult2
}

//test [Dictionary<String, Any>]
let dictionary = [
["a": 2, "k": 4, "b": 3, "l": 3, "c":7], 
["b": 3, "a": 2, "k": 4, "c":7, "l": 3]]

let sortedArray = sortWithTableColumn(datavalue: dictionary)

//print sorted array of arrays from SomeStructs
print(sortedArray) 
//print key from sorted array of arrays from SomeStructs
print(sortedArray[0][0].key)
```